# ASP.NET MVC Routing issue. Not mapping route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, routes, routedebugger

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I've encountered problem, which I can't solve. I've spent two days searching Google, but still nothing.

So, my situation is:
I'm trying to implement localization in my ASP.NET MVC application using routing.

`www.mysite.com/Home/Index` - for default (Russian)

`www.mysite.com/en/Home/Index` - for English

So I'm registering routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                        "Default",
                        "{controller}/{action}",
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
                        new { controller = "^[a-zA-z]{4,}$" }
             );

            routes.MapRoute(
                        "Localization",
                        "{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
                        new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
        }
```

Navigating to default: `www.mysite.com/Home/Index` works fine.
But when I try to navigate to `www.mysite.com/en/Home/Index` I get `404 error`.

What is more interesting, `RouteDebugger` does'n see my new route:

[image: RouteDebugger All Routes Table]

Adding more new routes, changing the order of their mapping or even deleting all my routes do nothing.
It seems that route `{controller}/{action}/{id}` is just the default route for MVC which was added "before me".

So, what could be the problem? I have totally no idea! I've seen screenshots of Rote Debugger from other sites and their routes are displayed. For example some other site: [Screenshot](http://haacked.com/images/haacked_com/WindowsLiveWriter/UrlRoutingDebugger_EEBA/route-debugger-screenshot.png)

Maybe I have to change something in `web.config`? I'm completely confused. Please help!
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Sounds like your site hasn't recompiled.  are you hosting it in iis Express/IIS/VWD Env?  try cleaning your solution and then hitting rebuild, see if that fixes it

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've cleaned the solution (Build -> Clean Solution) and rebuid it (Build -> Rebuild Solution) but still noting.

Comment: What version of MVC? Where is RegisterRoutes? Is it in the App_Start folder in the RouteConfig class? Where are you calling it? Your RouteDebugger output seems to be displaying a different set of routes than what you have defined. My guess is that you've got code on global.asax.cs that is registering routes (MVC <= 3 style), and your sample is in App_Start (MVC 4 style) but not being called.

Comment: Yeah! That works! Thank you very much!!! I'm using MVC 4. I have to map my routes in RoutConfig that is stored in App_Start folder. _Colin Young_, could you write your comment as full answer, so I can mark it as best answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC 4, RouteConfig.cs is stored in `App_Start`. If you create your project from the MVC 4 project wizard it should wire it all up for you. If not, you will need to call it from `global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // other stuff ...
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    // other stuff ...
}
```

Also, IIRC, the MVC 3 project wizard sets up all the default routes directly in `Application_Start`, so you'll need to remove those (or move them into `RegisterRoutes` as the case may be).

Answer (score 1):

RoutConfig is read sequentially and "Default {controller}/{action}" is very greedy. Move your "Localization" route code above the "Default" route and see if that helps.